# How to use Electron.NET to wrap an ASP.NET Core Single Page Application

Tags: asp.net-core, electron, single-page-application, electron.net

I created a SPA with ASP.NET Core and react/typescript by following this blog post: https://www.nolanbradshaw.ca/net-react-typescript-template

While debugging the project I use the following in my launchSettings.json

```
"MySPA": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5181",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    }
```

The SpaProxy settings in my .csproj file look like this...

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>client-app\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
    <SpaProxyServerUrl>http://localhost:3000</SpaProxyServerUrl>
    <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ElectronNET.API" Version="13.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" Version="2.4.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy" Version="6.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="client-app\src\components\TestPage.tsx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Services\Services.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="client-app\src\components\TestPage.tsx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />
    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)build\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles-&gt;'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="electron.manifest.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I would now like to wrap this project with Electron.net in order to run it as a local desktop app. I have installed nuget packages and followed setup instructions on the Electron.net [github](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET). I run my app via `electionize start`, everything looks to build correctly, and it opens up a blank electron window. The last few lines of my electronize output look like this.

```
ElectronHostHook handling started...
Invoke electron.cmd - in dir: C:\s-lab\repos\LxTraderV3\LxTraderV3\LxTraderV3\obj\Host\node_modules\.bin
electron.cmd "..\..\main.js"

Electron Socket IO Port: 8000
Electron Socket started on port 8000 at 127.0.0.1
ASP.NET Core Port: 8001
stdout: Use Electron Port: 8000

stdout: ASP.NET Core host has fully started.

ASP.NET Core Application connected... global.electronsocket iBNLmdfbkcPJRNlyAAAA 2023-03-01T21:45:18.720Z
stdout: BridgeConnector connected!
```

When I look at the developer tools in electron I see a request to http://localhost:8001/ with 404 error.

Where do I go from here to properly configure electron to host my project?

Comment: I have updated my answer, and give some suggestions for you, pls re-create a new project then use electron. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Please don't use the repo from the blog, there are some issues related the npm package.

At first, I want use the repo in that blog and always failed in my side, maybe I am using high version of npm and node. It always failed, then I create a new project with .net5. And it works.

You also can try to add any kind of web project and then use the `electron`, if you have finished your project, you need to make sure your project can run normally before using electron.

#### My Test Result

The output log in my side is different than you. And I found you are missing below.

```
info
stdout: : Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:8003
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info
stdout: : Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: F:\AspNetCore\ReactTypeScript.NET-master\Project2\obj\Host\bin
```

---

**My logs**

```
ElectronHostHook handling started...
Invoke electron.cmd - in dir: F:\AspNetCore\ReactTypeScript.NET-master\Project2\obj\Host\node_modules\.bin
electron.cmd "..\..\main.js"

Electron Socket IO Port: 8000
Electron Socket started on port 8000 at 127.0.0.1
ASP.NET Core Port: 8003
stdout: Use Electron Port: 8000

stdout: ASP.NET Core host has fully started.
info
stdout: : Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:8003
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info
stdout: : Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: F:\AspNetCore\ReactTypeScript.NET-master\Project2\obj\Host\bin

ASP.NET Core Application connected... global.electronsocket Jk0Cek48X1fg_pmtAAAA 2023-03-03T08:16:13.333Z
stdout: BridgeConnector connected!

stdout: warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
```

I also following the doc, add below code in project. And it works fine.

[image]

[image]